# Why in this example using callback function in forEach method gives wrong output?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use callback function with forEach method to print in the console the result of 3 prompts but instead I have 5 outputs.

```
const personalMovieDB = {
genres: [],
writeYourGenres: function () {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        let favoriteGenre = [];    
            while (favoriteGenre == null || favoriteGenre == "") {
                favoriteGenre = prompt(`Your favorite movie genre under number ${i}`);
                this.genres[i - 1] = favoriteGenre;
            }
            this.genres.forEach((item, i) => {
                console.log(`Favorite genre ${i+1} - ${item}`);
            });
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `this.genres.forEach(`…`);` be _outside_ the `for` loop?

Comment: The bigger mystery is why OP mentions only 5 outputs when it should be 6 (1+2+3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove printing functionality from a loop

```js
const personalMovieDB = {
  genres: [],
  writeYourGenres: function() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      let favoriteGenre = [];
      while (favoriteGenre == null || favoriteGenre == "") {
        favoriteGenre = prompt(`Your favorite movie genre under number ${i}`);
        this.genres[i - 1] = favoriteGenre;
      }
    }
    this.genres.forEach((item, i) => {
      console.log(`Favorite genre ${i+1} - ${item}`);
    });
  }
}

personalMovieDB.writeYourGenres()
```